# Can I receive a 2FA code via API in an automated way?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, bots

I am using a small bot on a website which requires 2FA. The login now is impossible in an automated way, so I would like to know if there exists a way to receive the 2FA code with an API request. The Twilio API seems to not be suited for this.
Thanks!

Comment: If you can receive the code via an API how is that going to be secure? A factor is something only the user has. For example some knowledge, access to a mail account, a device, a bio metrical attribute…

Comment: Ok, with a secret key or something similiar why should it be a problem. Can be stealen as any physical device